# PHP strtotime( YYYY-mm last day) a month off error

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying the following command in PHP 5.2.12 :

```
print (date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2009-12 last day')));
```

Regarding to the [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) :

```
date('m/d/y', strtotime('2009-03 last day')); # 03/31/09
```

it should display the last day of march 2009 (2009-03-31) !

Mine returns the last day of the previous month ? why ? :

```
2009-11-30
```

Comment: it's not manual, that's just user's post. you can ask her directly, I suppose http://stackoverflow.com/users/111362/katylava

Comment: Works right on my mac (php 5.3): 2009-12-31

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted fails in the manner you described; it seems that the description in the PHP manual pages (which as mentioned by SilentGhost is just a user comment) is non-verified code.

If you need the last day of a given month, try this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2009-12 next month - 1 hour"));
```

Comment: I always use 12 hours, just in case someone sometime decides that daylight savings day is the first or last day of some month.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP 5.3 try using the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime("2009-03-01");
    $date->modify("last day of previous month");
    echo $date->format("m/d/y");
?>
```

It must be 5.3 as `$date->modify("last day of previous month");` won't work in 5.2.* or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're simply using the relative format incorrectly, this works for me:

```
echo date('m/d/y', strtotime('last day of 2009-12'));
```

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

> `'last day' ' of'?` -- Sets the day to the last day of the current month. This phrase is best used together with a month name following it. -- `"last day of next month"`

Answer (score 0):

`date("Y-m-t", strtotime("201512"));`

For December 2015